# I'm getting a warning that is preventing me from running my program and I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: c++, hash

The code is supposed to read input from a file and put that info into a hashing table, and if any collisions arise, it's supposed to handle those as well. I'm not sure how to fix the error I'm getting with the line **`int count = 0`**, this is the error warning:

```
non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

..

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<map> 
#include <ctime>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;

struct record{
        char last_name[15] ;
        char first_name[15] ;
        unsigned int account_num ;
        unsigned int month ;
        unsigned int day ;
        unsigned int year ;
        float annual_salary ;
        char dept_code ; 
        char phone_num[12] ;
};

struct Node{
        record p ;
        struct Node * next ;
};
struct Hash{
        struct Node * head ;
        int count = 0 ;
};
Hash H[37] ;
/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head
   of a list and an int, appends a new node at the end  */
void append(struct Node** head_ref,record new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    struct Node *last = *head_ref;  /* used in step 5*/

    /* 2. put in the data  */
    new_node->p  = new_data;

    /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next of
          it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL;

    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
       *head_ref = new_node;
       return;
    }

    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;

    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node;
    return;
}

void insert(record r)
{
        int x = r.account_num %37 ;
        append(&(H[x].head),r) ;
}
map<int,string> m ;
void printdata()
{
        time_t now = time(0);
        char* dt = ctime(&now) ;
        int z = strlen(dt) ;
        int yea = 0 , temp = 1;
        z--;
        while(dt[z]!=' ')
        {
                yea += temp*(dt[z]-'0');
                temp = temp*10 ;
                z--;
        }
        int mont ;
        char ch[3] ;
        ch[0] = dt[4] ;
        ch[1] = dt[5] ;
        ch[2] = dt[6] ;
        for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
        {
                if(m[i]==ch)
                {
                        mont = i ;
                        break ;
                }
        }
        m[1] = "Jan" ;
        m[2] = "Feb" ;
        m[3] = "Mar" ;
        m[4] = "Apr" ;
        m[5] = "May" ;
        m[6] = "Jun" ;
        m[7] = "Jul" ;
        m[8] = "Aug" ;
        m[9] = "Sep" ;
        m[10] = "Oct" ;
        m[11] = "Nov" ;
        m[12] = "Dec" ;
        struct Node * q ;
        cout << "LAST Name       Acct Number     date of birth            annual salary          department code       age\n";
        for(int i=0;i<=36;i++)
        {
                q = (H[i].head);
                int cnt = 0 ;
                while(q!=NULL)
                {
                        cnt++;
                        q = q->next ;
                }
                temp = q->p.year - yea + (q->p.month - mont>=6 ? 1:0) ;
                q = H[i].head ; 
                cout << q->p.last_name <<" "<<q->p.account_num ;
                if(cnt>1)cout<<"*";
                cout <<" "<<m[q->p.month]<<". "<<q->p.day<<","<<q->p.year<<" "<<q->p.annual_salary<<" "<<q->p.dept_code<<" "<<temp<<"\n" ;;
                if(q==NULL)continue ;
                q = q->next ;
                while(q!=NULL)
                {
                        temp = q->p.year - yea + (q->p.month - mont>=6 ? 1:0) ;
                        cout << q->p.last_name <<" "<<q->p.account_num ;
                    cout <<" "<<m[q->p.month]<<". "<<q->p.day<<","<<q->p.year<<" "<<q->p.annual_salary<<" "<<q->p.dept_code<<" "<<temp<<"\n" ;;
                   q = q->next ;
                }
        }
        return ;
}
int main()
{

        record r ;
        freopen("data.txt","r",stdin);
        while(cin >> r.last_name)
        {
             cin >> r.first_name >> r.account_num >> r.month >> r.day >> r.year >> r.annual_salary >> r.dept_code ;
             if(cin >> r.phone_num) ;
             insert(r) ;
        }

        return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Is it an error or a warning?  You should be able to run an executable with a warning (we've done it at my shop).

Comment: Since the `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not standard, I'd begin with that.

Comment: You can use the ancient art of using constructors in structures.  Create a constructor in `Hash` that initializes the `count` member.

Comment: If you are actually using C++: 1) Use `new` not `malloc`.  `malloc` does not call constructors. 2) Prefer `std::string` and not character arrays.  3) Prefer `std::fstream` instead of `FILE *`.  4) Pass pointers by reference if you are going to modify them.

Comment: Your program would be more efficient by using an array of `std::string`, rather than a `map`.  A `map` is overkill for converting numbers to month names.

Comment: Also, implement `operator>>` for your `record` class.  You input loop becomes: `while (cin >> r)`.

Comment: *"non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11"*  So you *are* using the option -std=c++11, right?

Comment: @BoPersson: The diagnostic suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory. You are not allowed to initialize non-static data members within the struct declaration, as you do in line 27 of your code. Instead, you may, for example:

1. Define the constructor of the `Hash` struct and initialize the `count` member in the c-tor.
2. Initialize the count member every time after instantiating an object of the `Hash` struct. I would not recommend this solution, especially if you insist on declaring of the `Hash H[37]` array in the global scope (which I also would not recommend, but that is another question altogether.).

In the sense of point 1. above, the `Hash` class declaration could look like this:

```
struct Hash{
    Hash() :
        head(NULL),
        count(0)
    {}

    struct Node * head ;
    int count;
};
```